# C# Linq How to enumerate over time periods between two dates to get data for a graph

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a table of events that occur on certain dates, know i want to format the data to be able to draw a line graph of events over time. The data has a label which is the value on the x axis and data which is the value on the y axis.

The data should be between two dates, in this example its from and to and then it must be in time intervals of days

This was my first attempt.

```
var graphData = bookings.Where(x => x.DateCreated > from && x.DateCreated < to)
                        .GroupBy(x => new { x.DateCreated.Year, x.DateCreated.Month, x.DateCreated.Day })
                        .OrderBy(x => x.Key.Year).ThenBy(x => x.Key.Month).ThenBy(x => x.Key.Day)
                        .Select(x => new GraphData
                        {
                            Label = x.Key.Day + "/" + x.Key.Month + "/" + x.Key.Year,
                            Data = x.Count()
                        }).ToList();
```

This give the correct data for me to graph **but only** for the days which there where any events created.

I want to have the data for the days where nothing happened included in my graph so i can compare different kinds of events on the same graph.

I came up with this solution

```
var dateRanges = Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + to.Value
                           .Subtract(from.Value).Days)
                           .Select(offset => from.Value.AddDays(offset)).ToList();
var graphData = dateRanges.Select(day => new GraphData()
                {
                   Label = day.ToString("D"),
                   Data = bookings.Count(x => x.DateCreated.Date == day.Date)
                }).ToList();
```

It seems to be very inefficient.

Is there any way to do this with a linq query so that i don't have to do a count on each date?

Comment: "It seems to be very inefficient." Inefficient as in slow, or you just don't like the code?

Comment: @grek40 I would say both. Its not clean code, and its gonna query the db in every iteration of the for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your attempt is that it will do one query to the DB for each of your dates.  Instead do one query to get the dates that have data then merge it with your range of dates in memory.

```
var dbData = bookings.Where(x => x.DateCreated > from && x.DateCreated < to)
                     .GroupBy(x => x.DateCreated.Date)
                     .Select(grp => new { grp.Key, grp.Count() })
                     .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count);

var graphData = Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + to.Value.Date.Subtract(from.Date.Value).Days)
    .Select(offset => from.Value.Date.AddDays(offset))
    .Select(day => new GraphData()
    {
        Label = day.ToString("D"),
        Data = dbDate.TryGetValue(day, out var count) ? count : 0
    }).ToList();
```

Also make sure to use the `Date` in your calculations because the difference between "1-1-2017 23:00:00" and "1-2-2017 00:00:00" is less than a day so your range would end up being just "1-1-2017".

Comment: Very valid last point.  You could skip or miss data if you don't group by the date portion only.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the solution i was looking for